# Serializing calls using actors to prevent out of order of replying the messages

Tags: scala, akka

Say you have multiple front-end web servers who are updating another system e.g. a memcache server

If each web server updates memcache, you may have multiple web servers updating the same cache key

eg. Say this code is in all of our web servers

```
val cachedValue = memcacheClient.get("someKey123")
if(!cachedValue.isDefined) {
   memcacheClient.put("someKey123", getSOmeThingTOPutInCache("someKey123"))
}
```

Since this call is not sychronized, you will have multiple web servers updating the same key.

What I want to do is simply send a message to an Actor that will then update memcache for me.

How can I create an actor that will NOT update memcache using parallelism? i.e. only a single call at a time?

This kind of goes against what akka is for I'm guessing, but it is a use-case that I hope it can solve.

Comment: I don't think this case is against what Akka is for. If you create an ActorSystem with just one actor and inside the `receive` method of that actor you update your cache then it will happen one at a time. The `receive` will be called by a thread at a time. Moreover, the cache will be updated in the order you send messages to the actor.

Comment: If only one actor is responsible for memcached, you will have  serialized updates but (probably) a decrease in throughput and (certainly) lower failure tolerance.  This might be a good use case for cluster sharding such that you have an actor per key (or set of keys or whatever makes sense for your use case).

Comment: @Ryan true, I can send the message to a set of actors sharded by whatever makes sense.